# Relative form action removes 4th grade subdomain

Tags: html, url, post, request

I have issue with HTML form which is pointing its action to: /index.php?something=x

So its looks like

```
<form action="/index.php?something=x" method="POST">
```

I have production of application running on subdomain **xx**.example.com

When i submit form, everything works well, request is going to:

**xx**.example.com/index.php?something=x

But on development environment i have 4th grade url. Example: **yy**.**xx**.example.com

When i submit form on dev environment request **is not** going to https://**yy.xx**.example.com/index.php?something=x

but url is without **yy** => https://xx.example.com/index.php?something=x and it is wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Nothing, nowhere... :/ Nginx logs empty, php logs empty.

Answer (score 3):

It's not problem in URL, you can have domain or sub domain as you like.
it can be, as you said 4th grade URL or longer "https://zz.yy.xx.example.com/".
Tested in my localhost xampp and on real server with some test sub domain.

Try to fix your code, you have two action fields

```
action="POST"
```

Replace second "action" with "method". It should be like this:

```
<form action="/index.php?something=x" method="POST">
```

Comment: my mistake, code in production is right. In question is wrong.

Comment: Did you try to make a simple test page without any other code, except the form code, somethig like this `<form action="/index.php?something=x" method="post"><input type="submit" value="submit" /></form>`

Comment: I tried everything, nothing helped. What ever, solved this with creating absolute url's in router, so problem is now fixed. But not resolved.